# Excluding quotes from a variable string for a mongodb query

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am a mongodb newbie, having said that;
I am getting a user input string to perform a "Does Not Contain" mongo query.

And this regex with a "$not" ought to do it as I know.

```
db.collection.find( { item: { $not: /STRING GOES HERE/ } } )
```

But the thing is, since I make up the query with string concatenation the query looks like this (with a double quoted regex.)
i.e.

```
db.collection.find( { "item": { "$not": "/theString/" } } )
```

When i try it with robomongo I get

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $not needs a regex or a document",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

When I manually exclude the double quotes surrounding the regex I get the expected output.

I dont know if I am overcomplicating this with too much information, Please tell me how do I get this done? 
Simply, How do I exclude the double quotes surrounding the regex using Javascript ; or is there any other way to get this done.

Edit : I am using nodejs and mongoose for this.

Comment: What language? Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a regex from a string you need to use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```
var str = 'theString';
db.collection.find( { "item": { "$not": new RegExp(str) } } )
```

Comment: all I get is an empty object. Any idea why?
    
    Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $not cannot be empty

Comment: @DanDole Sounds like you may have a syntax error in your code.  Can you edit your question to show what you're trying?

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is, try not to use string concatenation.

In your Javascript that calls on Mongoose, create a Javascript object as the query and append to its prototype as follows...

```
var query = {};
query.Item = {$not : "theString"};
```

Pass this to your Mongoose model.

For example,

```
youMongooseModel.find(query, function(err, result){});
```